# iphone iads animation

Tags: iphone

Hi all I am working on the iAds. I want to animate the ad banner when the ad changes. Is there any way to make them animate automatically? or is it that we should do it manually each time the ad changes.?

Answer (score 1):

The standard technique is to create the iAd banner off-screen, wait for notification that the iAd banner has successfully received an ad, then to animate it from off-screen to on-screen.   Likewise, if there was an error in receiving the ad, animate the ad banner from on-screen to off-screen, until a new add is successfully received.

Like this:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.isBannerVisible)
    {
        CGFloat yCoord = ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) ? 1024.0 : 480.0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectMake( 0, yCoord, banner.frame.size.width, banner.frame.size.height );
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.isBannerVisible = NO;
    }
}

-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    if (!self.isBannerVisible)
    {
        CGFloat yCoord = ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) ? 1024.0 - banner.frame.size.height : 480.0 - banner.frame.size.height;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectMake( 0, yCoord, banner.frame.size.width, banner.frame.size.height );
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.isBannerVisible = YES;
    }
}
```